# Routing app coverage file not copied to the simulator

Tags: ios, xcode6

Since updating to Xcode 6, I see this warning every time I run the app on the simulator. My app has a routing app coverage file and I want it copied to the simulator but it's not happening. This seems like it might be a bug. Is there a workaround?

[image: Routing App Coverage file error]

Comment: See this issue, too. The funny thing is the Maps app routing feature works just fine so it's just the ugly alert popping up each launch.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error some time back, because XCode may be using a precompiled version of the app.

This is how I solved it:

In xCode, make sure that your app isn't running in the simulator (click the stop button), then 
`Build menu > Clean target` or `SHIFT-CMD-K`.

Additionally, clean the content in the Derived Data folder `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`.

*Hope it works for you.*

Comment: The old "clean everything and nuke derived data" trick, eh? Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it didn't fix it.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I'll keep on looking for an alternative solution.